# String() Function error - Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

I have this function in JS

```
<script>

    var currentLocation = window.location.href;

    function AddCardToTrello() {
      Trello.addCard({
      url: currentLocation,
      name: String({{ soproduct.product }}),
      due: {{ soproduct.required_date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"  }}
    });
    }

    </script>
```

That gives me this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

This is how it looks like when parsed

```
<script>

var currentLocation = window.location.href;

function AddCardToTrello() {
  Trello.addCard({
  url: currentLocation,
  name: String(1 4343rfcdc 54446),
  due: 07/30/2016
});
}

</script>
```

The error is in this line

```
 name: String(1 4343rfcdc 54446),
```

When the value is id (numeric) it works ok and I am not getting any error.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because the Javascript engine doesn't know that '1 4343rfcdc 54446' is a string, so you would need to wrap it with quotes. And if you do so, you wont need the String constructor because it will already be a string.

```
Trello.addCard({
  url: currentLocation,
  name: "{{ soproduct.product }}",
  due: "{{ soproduct.required_date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"  }}"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

may something like:

```
function AddCardToTrello() {
      Trello.addCard({
      url: currentLocation,
      name: String("{{ soproduct.product }}"),
      due: "{{ soproduct.required_date|date:'SHORT_DATE_FORMAT'  }}"
    });
```

or even

```
function AddCardToTrello() {
      Trello.addCard({
      url: currentLocation,
      name: "{{ soproduct.product }}",
      due: "{{ soproduct.required_date|date:'SHORT_DATE_FORMAT'  }}"
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you are missing quotes to indicate that its a string write something like;

```
name : "1 4343rfcdc 54446",
```